# How to install xampp on google cloud windows instance?

Tags: windows, xampp, cloud, instance

I want to deploy project on google cloud. I had install xampp on google VM and paste my project in c:xampp\htdocs. but I not able to access it from other machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create d drive, allow access for everyone to do anything on d drive.

Install xampp in d drive and copy your application folder in htdocs.

Press Start -> open Windows Defender Firewall with advanced security.

Select Windows Defender Firewall Properties from center of the screen.

In Domain profile change the inbound connection from blocked to allow, do the same for private profile and public profile.

Change index.php in htdocs - change the default action from dashboard to the name of your application folder.

Open your application's folder -> Then open application folder -> open config folder -> open config.php -> update baseurl in config.php - change localhost to ip address of windows instance.

Open any browser from any pc and just enter the ip address of the windows instance and you can see your application.